# I can't store an image to the Firebase/Firestore that has high resolution

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

So I'm making the messenger using React and Firebase/Firestore.

When I was sending images in messenger that are 20KB, they were succesfully sended. But when I sent 1000KB image, the error came out in the terminal.

Can you help find the to send images that are more than 1000 Kilobytes.

---

Error #1: GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fatuber-1f4b8.appspot.com/o/07537320-9363-4608-8a02-f94535fc7323 404

Error #2: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object '07537320-9363-4608-8a02-f94535fc7323' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

1. [Picture of how I'm trying to send the 20KB
   image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY8es.png) |
2. [Picture with succesfuly sended image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pmbb.png) |
3. [Picture of how I'm trying to send 1200KB
   image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkOWz.png) |
4. [Picture with error
   when I tried to send 1200Kb
   image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXeiW.png)

**Input.js**
File with sending system.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import Img from "../../static/chat/add-img.png";
import Attach from "../../static/chat/attach.png";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";
import { ChatContext } from "./ChatContext";
import {
  arrayUnion,
  doc,
  serverTimestamp,
  Timestamp,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db, storage } from "../../firebase";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";

const Input = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [img, setImg] = useState(null);

  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { data } = useContext(ChatContext);

  const handleSend = async () => {
    if (img) {
      const storageRef = ref(storage, uuid());

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, img);

      uploadTask.on(
        (error) => {
          //TODO:Handle Error
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
            await updateDoc(doc(db, "chats", data.chatId), {
              messages: arrayUnion({
                id: uuid(),
                text,
                senderId: currentUser.uid,
                date: Timestamp.now(),
                img: downloadURL,
              }),
            });
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "chats", data.chatId), {
        messages: arrayUnion({
          id: uuid(),
          text,
          senderId: currentUser.uid,
          date: Timestamp.now(),
        }),
      });
    }

    await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid), {
      [data.chatId + ".lastMessage"]: {
        text,
      },
      [data.chatId + ".date"]: serverTimestamp(),
    });

    await updateDoc(doc(db, "userChats", data.user.uid), {
      [data.chatId + ".lastMessage"]: {
        text,
      },
      [data.chatId + ".date"]: serverTimestamp(),
    });

    setText("");
    setImg(null);
  };
  return (
    <div className="input">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        value={text}
      />
      <div className="send">
        <img src={Attach} alt="" />
        <input
          type="file"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          id="file"
          onChange={(e) => setImg(e.target.files[0])}
        />
        <label htmlFor="file">
          <img src={Img} alt="" />
        </label>
        <button onClick={handleSend}>Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: Well, I don't see any error.

Comment: The picture of the error is in the fourth screenshot on the right side of the second monitor in the terminal.

Comment: That's the thing, we are not here to watch pictures. Edit your question and paste error as text, so everyone can copy and paste it.

Comment: Sorry for the long reply